# numpy 1.6.1 and python 2.7 along with ropemacs crash code completion

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, ropemacs, pymacs

so now that I updated python from 2.7 to 2.7.2 i can no longer invoke rope-code assist in emacs.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
```

I have the typical rope 0.9.3, ropemode-0.1-rc2, pymacs 0.24-beta2, ropemacs 0.6

when doing M-/ or M-x rope-code-assist I get the following trace on numpy namespaces which I didn't get in python 2.7:
(Same deal for sciPy; paradoxically, matplotlib still works)

```
pymacs-report-error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  <abridged>
  File "c:\devel\Python\2.7-bin\lib\site-packages\rope\base\ast.py", line 30, in walk
    return method(node)
  File "c:\devel\Python\2.7-bin\lib\site-packages\rope\base\evaluate.py", line 166, in _Call
    if '__new__' in pyobject:
  File "c:\devel\Python\2.7-bin\lib\site-packages\rope\base\pyobjects.py", line 32, in __contains__
    return key in self.get_attributes()
  File "c:\devel\Python\2.7-bin\lib\site-packages\rope\base\utils.py", line 10, in _wrapper
    setattr(self, name, func(self, *args, **kwds))
  File "c:\devel\Python\2.7-bin\lib\site-packages\rope\base\builtins.py", line 81, in get_attributes
    result = _object_attributes(self.builtin, self)
  File "c:\devel\Python\2.7-bin\lib\site-packages\rope\base\builtins.py", line 123, in _object_attributes
    child = getattr(obj, name)
AttributeError: __abstractmethods__
```

Comment: Post it as the anser. This fixes it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution here: https://bitbucket.org/agr/rope/issue/15/crashes-with-attributeerror.

See also http://bugs.python.org/issue10006.